# Include needed for Python/Django

Tags: python, django, include

First, let me preface this by saying I am brand new to both Python and Django.  I would like to be using a language I already know, like and prefer, alas the frameworks simply don't exist for them.  Bottom line, I'm no "pythonista."

At any rate, I'm on the first couple of pages of a Django tutorial, and am at the point of creating the data model.  Right away I see that the example hardcodes things like the max length of character fields right there in the model.  This is something I simply won't do, as this information will not only change often and be required in many places, but it will also be used when I code up backend applications in another programming language.

The critical issue is, I won't be using python for backend stuff.  I will be using another language.  Programs in that language will need access to things like the max length of character fields.

In any of the other languages I use, this is a simple matter.  I simply stick something like a max length in a file called MAXLENGTH, and include that file wherever I need it.  If max length ever needs to change (and it will), I change it in one place.  It is then changed in all other places, no matter what other languages are used.

I need this capability in Python/Django, or something which will achieve similar effect with minimal hassle.  I did find an import statement, but it doesn't seem to do exactly what I want (it seems to import Python code, but I can't use a Python-only solution here).

Note that I'm not likely to entertain exotic, complicated solutions involving lots of complicated declarations of classes and what not.  It's a simple problem, I need a simple solution.

Also, I would accept a solution in either Python, or Django (if Django has some special capability in this regard).

Much thanks.

Comment: First off, you have to specify the max length for a field in a django model as a hardcoded value because it 1-to-1 correlates with the ORM and automatically creating your database tables. Your tables are hardcoded to that value anyways. This value would NOT be changing randomly. Second, I don't understand exactly what your question is. You just want a constants module? Have you looked at the standard `settings.py` in django? Have you read how models work, in conjuntion with your database?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html

Comment: I can't understand this "question" either. The DB table knows the max length so any other language/application interacting with the database can get the max length from the table.

Comment: Don't know why this question is hard to understand - let me try again.  Anyone beyond a novice programmer knows you don't hardcode a "magic number" (value) in a program.  You put it at the top in a constant, a macro, a #define - whatever.  That way you can change it one time and it will change everywhere in the code it is referenced.  You guys already know that.  Now the point is, I can't use a "constant" at the top because I will also need this constant in other files used by other non-python programs.  Thus I'd like to be able to define the constant in one file and let everything include it.

Answer (score 1):

**The common way in django**

I believe this is the closest to what you are asking. Any app you create in django can set up custom settings in the `settings.py` for users to configure. This allows easy distribution. Read here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/settings/#creating-your-own-settings

You set defaults, and document them. Then users can overload them in the `settings.py` of the project to customize the values.

**The less common way in django, but maybe common from a general programming standpoint**

In terms of "magic numbers", I don't think a database field property is really a magic number. Its usually something that is specific to the design of the model, but if you really don't want to use the settings.py, and all you want is a constants module then just do something like this:

*constants.py*

```
MODEL1_FIELD1_MAXLENGTH = 100
```

*models.py*

```
import constants

a = CharField(max_length=constants.MODEL1_FIELD1_MAXLENGTH)
```

But honestly, I don't see this happen very often. The value is usually coupled closely to the design and has an impact on other code that will use the model, like formatting situations and whatnot. Its kind of like allowing an end-user to set arbitrary values to internal buffers. It could impact code that expects a reasonable buffer because its part of the design decision. But I do understand the idea of constants from a general standpoint. Its just not that common in this specific framework, at this specific area.

Technically you could use a common format like JSON for your config file, but you would have to decide how and when it would decode. In django, the modules get loaded once and stay loaded through the life of the django instance. This might be something you init from the settings.py to ensure the order of operations.

*config.json*

```
{
    "MAX_LENGTH": 100
}
```

*constants.py*

```
import json

CONSTANTS = {}
CONSTANTS_FILE = "config.json"

def initConstants():
    global CONSTANTS_FILE
    with open(CONSTANTS_FILE) as f:
        CONSTANTS_FILE = json.load(f)
        print CONSTANTS_FILE
        # {"MAX_LENGTH": 100}
```

Comment: If OP needs to get at that number from outside Python, it'd be trivial to either parse the `constants.py` file, or (probably a bad idea because then Django does too much file I/O) store it in some non-Python format that's parsed inside `constants.py`. I agree, though, that this seems like a general bias against "magic numbers" that isn't really that applicable in this specific setting.

Comment: It looks like the closest I can come to what I want is this "constants" file, which I've already implemented and it works.  Thing is, I can't import such a thing in my other languages.  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @RG: This bit about other languages needing to share this settings file is something that probably should have been given more attention in your question. Is what you are after a common format like a JSON config file? For that, you would have to have your constants.py (or your settings.py) deserialize it. The reason people are so confused is because you are doing something very specialized and haven't talked much about this area.

Comment: @jdi, I specified at the open (go look), and in most every comment I made that the prime directive was other languages needing to share the info.

Comment: @RG: Yes I realize that, but if you already have other languages and you are making them share common data, why not specifically say what format you are using to share between them? Is it JSON? Is it XML? Is it some custom format you parse in each language? If you had just said "I am working in language x y and z, and I prefer to use a JSON config file between all of them", then you would have immediately started getting answers reflecting how to do that. But all you said was you want a magic "include" statement that is not the `import` statement, that can handle any arbitrary format.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the comment, by jdi, you will need to add the max_length property to the CharField's but what you can do is:

Add a property at the top of the models.py or any other "Common" file say:

```
MAX_LENGTH=100
```

Then, import Commpn.py

```
a = CharField(max_length=Common.MAX_LENGTH, ....)
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: You are on the right track to what I'm asking.  The problem with your solution seems to be it's a "python only" solution, but thanks for trying to help.  @everyone - yes, I already know I will need the max length coded.  The point is, I don't want to say "maxlength=24", I want to say "maxlength = <include MAXLENGTH>" the point being it can also be included by non-python programs.

Comment: Good example. But even with this I dont get what the OP is after. You could just get this value back from the model later if you really needed to query the property. I just dont get why a table parameter would need to be made dynamic. Your model IS your configuration.

Comment: I'm gonna have backend stuff written in other languages (in fact I already do) and this stuff will be accessed through fcgi etc.  I don't want this stuff to have to query proprietary django/python models "upline" through fcgi from where they sit on the backend.  What is 10x easier for me and cleaner and always works is to include the necessary definitions in ALL files written in ALL languages at compile time, not try to pass crap around and access it run-time with all the extra coding and crap.  Thanks.

Comment: "I just dont get why a table parameter would need to be made dynamic. Your model IS your configuration." -- It isn't being made dynamic (it is a static database parameter needed to define the table).  It is being made easily changeable when and if that needs to occur.  I'm surprised folks think this is weird - I learned to code this way decades ago.  I would never put any "magic values" in code, whether strings, size constraints, whatever.  All "magic values" always need to be placed where they can easily be changed everywhere with one change in one place.

Comment: @RG: This may very well be something you learned decades ago and a common practice, but I'm being honest when I say I have never seen a django app/project with a common-format config file that specified the values of every single model it has. A project can have many models, and a model can have many fields, and I have always seen these database field properties defined at the site of the model. Additionally, apps in django are meant to be distributable. If you make your entire project dependent on a central JSON/XML/WHATEVER config file, it is no longer a django idiom.

Comment: @jdi: point taken.  I understand that pythonistas/djangoists will answer idiomatically, and they should.  It is also appreciated.  However, as I said at the very top, I'm no pythonista/djangoist, and with all due respect don't want to be (it's not my language of choice).  I'm more of a functional guy, and if I do OO I prefer smalltalk as I did decades ago.  I view this thing as a way to automate some of the awful web crap so I can get on with the REAL work of the backend stuff, where I have my own idioms.  Btw, looked at rails, but with all the @,#,$,: etc it looked like crap.

Comment: I'm just barely scratching the surface of this thing now as I continue to work tutorials, but I must say, as I get deeper into it, the thing seems quite nice for what it is and what it does.  I hope I end up being as productive in it as I'm hoping, and hats off to the pythonistas and djangoists (and railists for that matter).

Comment: @RG: I completely respect your experience and your preferences. And Im happy you are starting to find things you appreciate about django. Its a very large and robust framework. And that being said, certain things are laid out the way they are to take that "awful web crap" off our hands.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't rocket science.

Create a constants file, say constants.txt.  Put name/value pairs in that file in an easily-parseable format.  For example name:value.  Write a small program in your language of choice (Python would be great for this).  This program reads in constants.txt, and then writes out an appropriate file for each of the languages you will be working with (like constants.py, constants.h, etc.)

For example, if constants.txt contained an entry of 'MODEL1_FIELD1_MAX_LENGTH: 20', then constants.h could contain an entry of the form '#define MODEL1_FIELD1_MAX_LENGTH 20', but constants.py would contain an entry of the form 'MODEL1_FIELD1_MAX_LENGTH=20'.  You get the picture.

Now make that little program be run automatically as part of your projects build process any time constants.txt is changed.

There you go--your constants kept in one file, yet always synchronized and available for any language you use.

Comment: Yup, certainly doable, and appreciate the suggestion.  But as I said at the outset, I wouldn't be entertaining exotic solutions that are more complicated than they should be.  A simple "include" would solve this just fine without the need for all the complexity and jumping through hoops.

Comment: @RG: The problem is that you would need to specify what a simple "include" would be, if its not a python module. You can't just "include" arbitrary code. If its not python, it has to be some other format that can be decoded. You might want to update your question with what format you really do want to use that will be common between python and your "other languages".